# Does MS lib.exe support DLL symbol redirection like '==' in dlltool

Tags: c

e.g. If I have a libtest.dll file which export symbol __ugly_name, I want to use pretty_name in the source file and lib file, I can do

```
    D:\var\tmp\build>type t-dll.c

      main() { pretty_name(); }

    D:\var\tmp\build>type libtest.def

      EXPORTS
        pretty_name == __ugly_name

    D:\var\tmp\build>dlltool -k -m i386 --input-def libtest.def  --dllname libtest.dll --output-lib libtest.dll.a

    D:\var\tmp\build>gcc -o t-dll.exe t-dll.c -L. -ltest

    The result t-dll.exe  reference symbol '__ugly_name' in libtest.dll file.
    VERY GOOD !

But for MS lib.exe, 'pretty_name=__ugly_name' does not do the trick:

D:\var\tmp\build>type libtest.def

  EXPORTS
    pretty_name=__ugly_name

D:\var\tmp\build>cl /nologo /MD /Fet-dll-vc.exe t-dll.c libtest.lib

t-dll-vc.exe still reference non-exist symbol 'pretty_name' in libtest.dll file.
```

SADLY. Does MS lib.exe support DLL symbol redirection ?
Thanks.

Comment: There's no evidence of you using the .def file at all.  I don't see a link command that uses the /DEF option when the DLL is getting linked.  A .def file isn't used when linking the EXE.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your 'ugly' name is being decorated as a stdcall function which gets a double underscore prefix and an @nn suffix where nn is the number of bytes of stack used by the function call. You can rename these by just declaring the undecorated name in your .def file. So if your code currently produces `__MyApiFunc@4` create a .def file as below and include it using the link.exe -lib option or with the compiler following the -link flag as `cl ...c_flags... -link -dll -lib:myapi.def ...linkflags...`

```
LIBRARY yourlibname
EXPORTS
    MyApiFunc
```

Basically you don't need the equals to get the undecorated name exported. You need to do this for most DLLs as the usual Windows convention is stdcall functions with undecorated names. Once you have a DLL like this you can use if from Visual Basic and .Net just like a normal Windows OS provided DLL. (Assumuing you really did have stdcall functions).

Comment: NO, they are completely different names, and the DLL file is out of control. e.g. HorizLayCoordToHorizWinCoord to xl_to_xw

Comment: Then that is almost certainly C++ mangled names being exported from the DLL. C++ exports are generally a bad idea as the name mangling is only compatible with client code that uses the same compiler (sometimes even the same version of the same compiler). Usual best practice is to wrap your exported API declarations with 'extern "C" { .... }' so ensure a C compatible API which will get you either _cdecl or stdcall functions with sensible names.

Comment: NO. It's not C++ mangled name, and the DLL file is out of control. I can not fix the DLL file, just can do DLL symbol redirection like '==' in dlltool. But it seems that MS lib.exe no such feature ?